# $\mathbb{C}$ is a one-dimensional complex vector space. What is its dimension when regarded as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

$\mathbb{C}$ is a one-dimensional complex vector space. What is its dimension when regarded as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$?

I don't understand how $\mathbb{C}$ is one-dimensional. Please help me understand that.

Also, I'm pretty sure that when the field is reals we have $\dim(\mathbb{C})=2$. Since when $\alpha$ is real and $z=a+bi$ is complex we have $\alpha z=\alpha a+\alpha bi=\alpha a(1,0)+\alpha b(0,i)$.

How does this look? Any solutions or help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: $\mathbb C$ as an $\mathbb R$-vector space is two dimensional. A natural basis is $\{ 1, i \}$, as you suggest.

Comment: What about when the field is complex?

Comment: $\mathbb C$ as an $\mathbb C$-vector space is one dimensional. Any field as a vector space over itself is one dimensional. It has a basis of $\{ 1 \}$.

Comment: @SimonS That doesn't really shed light, it just restates what the OP doesn't understand.

Comment: Hm, I did articulate a basis in each case, which is used to define finite dimension. Why don't we wait for the OPer to ask a follow up.

Comment: @1233dfv To understand why $\Bbb C$ is one dimensional, try to think of a basis for $\Bbb C$ as a vector space over itself.  You need to find a collection of elements $\{\alpha_{1}, \alpha_{2}, \dots \}$ (not necessarily countable) in $\Bbb C$ such that they are linearly independent and every element in $\Bbb C$ can be written as $\sum c \alpha$, where $c$ is a scalar.  But if we are talking about $\Bbb C$ over itself, then the scalars are complex numbers, too.  So $c$ can be any complex number.  It should immediately become clear that we only have 1 element in this basis.

Comment: Yeah, how come $\dim_F(F^n)=n$? When I multiply a complex number by a complex number I either get a real number or a complex number.

Comment: @1233dfv That element is $1$, i.e., the basis is $ \{ 1 \}$.  Why?  Well, is this a linearly independent set?  Of course, since it only has one element. Can every element in $\Bbb C$ be written as a "combination" of $1$ (with scalar in $\Bbb C$)?  Of course.  For any $c \in \Bbb C$, $c = 1 \cdot c$.  So $\{1 \}$ is a basis for $\Bbb C$ as a vector space over itself.  Since the dimension corresponds to the number of basis elements, the dimension of $\Bbb C$ is 1 as a vector space over itself.

Comment: @user46944 I'm sorry, that isn't clear at all to me. I must be missing it.

Answer (score 18):

$\mathbb C$ as an $\mathbb C$-vector space is one dimensional. Any field as a vector space over itself is one dimensional. It has a basis of $\{ 1 \}$.

To see this, consider an element $f \in \mathbb F$ in a field $\mathbb F$. Write $\vec f$ when we are considering $f$ as a member of the vector space. Then as we can write $\vec f = f \vec 1$ for all $\vec f \in \mathbb F$, the multiplicative identity $\vec 1$ is in itself a perfectly good basis for $\mathbb F$.

---

Using that notation for $\mathbb C$ as an $\mathbb R$-vector space, we can write any vector $\vec z \in \mathbb C$ is

$$\vec z = a\vec 1 + b \vec i \quad \text{ with } a, b \in \mathbb R$$

Hence $\{ \vec 1, \vec i \}$ is a basis.

---

As for why the dimension of $\mathbb F^n$ is $n$, as you ask in the comments: that's because there is a basis $\{ (1,0,\cdots, 0), (0, 1, \cdots, 0), \cdots, (0,0 , \cdots, 0, 1) \}$ with $n$ elements. Hence by definition of dimension

$$\dim(\mathbb F^n) = n$$

Comment: Well, strictly speaking, in the first part you'd also have to show that $\{1\}$ is linearly independent. In the second part, you also need to state that $\vec 1$ and $\vec i$ are linearly independent.

Comment: If you consider $C^2$ as a vector space over C then basis can be {(1, 0), (01) }. I just want to know if a basis can be {(1, i), (i, 1) }.. I am just having a doubt the scalars need to be from the field but the numbers which come inside the basis should also be from the same field or not. Like say if you would take C^2 as a field over R then a basis vectors are (1, 0), (0, i) and so on. But field is R yet an "i" is coming in (0, i)... Could you please help in these 2 particular doubts.

Answer (score 13):

To answer your question of why the dimension of $\Bbb C$ as a vector space over itself is $1$:

Do you agree that the dimension of a vector space is the same as the number of basis elements?  So to find the dimension of a vector space over a scalar field, you just have to find a basis for the vector space and then the dimension will be the number of elements in the basis.

Well, if $S$ is a vector space and $F$ is our scalar field, then a basis of $S$ (over $F$) is a set of elements $\{s_{1}, s_{2}, \dots, s_{n} \} \subseteq S$ such that the set is linearly independent, and for each $s \in S$, we can find scalars $f_{1}, f_{2}, \dots, f_{n} \in F$ such that $s = \sum \limits_{i = 1}^{n} f_{i}s_{i}$.

Now that we have that out of the way, replace the above stuff with $S = \Bbb C$ and $F = \Bbb C$. The dimension of $S$ over $F$ is a collection of elements in $S$ such that for each $s \in S$, we can write it as a linear combination of the collection of elements, and the collection of elements is linearly independent.

Here is my candidate for a basis of $\Bbb C$ over $\Bbb C$.  It is $\{ 1 \}$.  Don't believe me that this is a basis?  Check the two conditions:

1) Is it a linearly independent set?  Well, for which scalars $c \in \Bbb C$ do we have $c \cdot 1 = 0$?  Only $c = 0$, so yes, it is a linearly independent set.

2)  Does it span $\Bbb C$ (over the field of scalars $\Bbb C$)?  Well, let $\alpha \in C$.  Can we find a scalar $c \in \Bbb C$ such that $\alpha = c \cdot 1$?  Yes, just let $c = \alpha$.  Obviously, $\alpha \cdot 1 = \alpha$.  So $\{1 \}$ spans $\Bbb C$ as a vector space over itself.

Since $\{ 1 \}$ satisfies the criteria to be a basis of $\Bbb C$ over itself, and since the set only has one element, then $\Bbb C$ has dimension $1$ as a vector space over itself.

Comment: If you consider $C^2$ as a vector space over C then basis can be {(1, 0), (01) }. I just want to know if a basis can be {(1, i), (i, 1) }.. I am just having a doubt the scalars need to be from the field but the numbers which come inside the basis should also be from the same field or not. Like say if you would take C^2 as a field over R then a basis vectors are (1, 0), (0, i) and so on. But field is R yet an "i" is coming in (0, i)... Could you please help in these 2 particular doubts.

Answer (score 2):

The complex numbers as a vector space over the field of real numbers is of dimension $2$. The two vectors $1$ and $i$ form a basis and any complex vector $a+ib$ is a linear combination of the two vectors $1$ and $i$, multiplied by real scalars $a$ and $b$ and added.

The complex numbers as a vector space over the field of complex numbers is of dimension $1$. Chose any vector in this space. You can multiply it with a scalar $a+bi$ (scalar because the field is the field of complex numbers) to get the arbitrary vector $a+bi$ (now $a+bi$ is any vector in the complex vector space, got by multiplying a unit vector $1$ with the scalar $a+bi$).

Comment: Please use MathJax.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: This answer to a four-year-old question adds nothing to the existing answers.